# Show that the score staistics, $S$, can be written as $S=(1-\hat\beta)^2\frac{n}{\hat\beta^2}$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

Can someone help me with part B of this question please? I am completely stuck and do not know how to proceed. Hints rather than answers appreciated please as this is allowed under my schools rules

[image]

I have defined what the score test is and made the substitutions according to the given value for $$E[-l"(B_0)] = \frac{n}{B_0}^2 $$ and the calculated value for $$(l'(B_0))^2 = ((\frac{n}{B_0} -\sum_{i=0}^n log(Xi))^2 $$. When plugging both into the value for the Score Statistic I get the following $$ S = ((\frac {n}{B_0} - \sum_{i=0}^n log(Xi))^2 * \frac{B_0^2}{n} $$ I am unsure how to remove the $B_0$ value in place for the MLE, $ \hat{B} $. I evaluated the Score statistic under the Null Hypotehsis such that, $H_0: B = 1$ yet remain stuck how to proceed. I have tried the substitution $\sum_{i=0}^n log(Xi) = \frac{n}{\hat{B}} $ but this has got me nowhere. I have attempted AdamO's comments below but cannot seem to proceed

Written work of my current progress:
[image]

Comment: stats.SE supports math typesetting which would make your post easier to read. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Done my best with it there

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1. Write out the score function $\dot{\mathcal{l}}$. you probably already did this on your way to calculating the information, but may have forgotten to take note of it.
2. Appeal to the definition of the score test. Roughly (for univariate test): Score(null parameter)^2 / Expected Information(null parameter). Use algebra, remembering the MLE is a function of the sufficient statistic.

Comment: Here is my working thus far, please see an edit to my original post. I am not able to take the hint you are suggesting about the sufficiency and the MLE. Possibly factorization?

Comment: But see my last about about the MLE and sufficient statistic. In other words, how else might we write $\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i$?

Comment: Maybe $nlogx_i$?

Comment: no. $\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i = n/\hat{\beta}$

Comment: Oh, I have tried this substitution before and got lost in the algebra as I could not eliminate $B_0$...